# Symptoms not covered by spring security in spring boots

Tags: oauth-2.0

The security login page does not appear and the password does not appear on the console when running the built-in tomcat after creating it in Spring Security maven.
dependencies에서 (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.7.16(omitted for dupplicate)) 라 고 나옵니다.

I thought the security password would come out of the console after applying the dependency in maven and running the built-in tomcat, but it doesn't come out. Security is not applicable.